# Problem with indexing children while running v-for directive

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

As you will see bellow i'm v-foring on array form Store.

```
<q-tab-panel v-for="(detailGoal, index) in $store.state.documents[0].document.content.mainGoal.detailGoals" :key="index" :name="detailGoal.title">
        
  <div class="text-h6">{{detailGoal.title}}</div>
  <div>{{idx}}</div>

  <!-- jj. this is next component -->
  <goals-details :thisIndex="index"/>
      
</q-tab-panel>
```

I also have button that push new element to this array and it's work fine.

```
//.jj it's in mutations
      ADD_DETAIL_GOAL(store, detailGoal: detailGoal){
        if(store.documents){store.documents[0].document.content.mainGoal.detailGoals.push(detailGoal)}
      },
```

On refreshing the site i recived default number of children with correct propsed index'es
but when i start to adding new children they show up but not with good idex'es
Does any one had this problem? please help.

[image]

Comment: Vue use `:key` attribute to identify vnodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list. So try to use some key that is unique to your item like `item.id`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem, it's just your lack of knowledge about programming. V-for loop index is completely different index then index in your array. Instead of using `.push()` method, use `.unshift()` method, and it should work. This is a quick fix to your problem. Instead, you should create your own ID for data in arrays because you might have problems with deleting correct documents in array. For example, you might have some getter or computed property with will sort the original array creating a new one and give it to v-for loop.

Comment: Adding new elements to the front of the arr do not change much. They still don't recive proper index.  Probably I will do it as you said by uniqe id's.

Comment: @JaneJacek Using `.unshift()` all data in array change their indexes data with was index 5 became index 6 and so on.

Comment: It's true indeed, more, when i use index for tab label - :label="index" they are named 1,2,3... .  The oldest one  has the bigest nr  but propsed value of index for the new ones are now 0